# как разбить код телеграм бота(на библиотеке telebot) на модули python

Tags: python, telebot

```
user_choise = {
     
    }

click = {
     
}

connect1 = sqlite3.connect("tovar.db", check_same_thread=False)
cursor1 = connect1.cursor()

connect2 = sqlite3.connect("users.db",check_same_thread=False)
cursor2 = connect2.cursor()

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])

def about(call):

    click[call.from_user.id]=0
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,one_time_keyboard=True)
    about_you = telebot.types.KeyboardButton(text = "about you")
    start_shopping = telebot.types.KeyboardButton(text = "start shopping")
    keyboard.add(about_you,start_shopping)
    about_sms = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, text = 'you are register in hikan shop',reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(about_sms,start_shop)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def start_shop(call):

    list_ids = []
    cursor2.execute("SELECT id FROM login_id")
    rows = cursor2.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        for id in row:
            list_ids.append(id)

    if call.text == "about you" and call.from_user.id in list_ids:

        cursor2.execute(f"SELECT * FROM login_id WHERE id = {call.from_user.id}")
        info = cursor2.fetchone()

        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,"you are register in 'hikan shop' and there are some information about you.\n"
                         "Please,check thats a valid data, because information about you can be use to make delivery.\n\n"
                         f"id: {info[0]}\n"
                         f"name: {info[1]}\n"
                         f"phone number: {info[2]}\n"
                         f"your role: {info[3]}\n"
                         f"you bought recently: {None}"
                        )
        connect1.commit()

    if call.text == "start shopping":

        cursor1.execute("SELECT category FROM tovars")
        categories = cursor1.fetchall()

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,one_time_keyboard=True)
        list_of_categories = []

        for categ_in_list in categories:
            for categ_in_tuple in categ_in_list:
                list_of_categories.append(categ_in_tuple)

        for category in list(set(list_of_categories)):
            category = types.KeyboardButton(text = category)
            markup.add(category)

        wait_for_choise = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, text = "select category",reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(wait_for_choise,choise)
        
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def choise(call):
    
    chosen_categ = call.text
   
    
    cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM tovars WHERE category = '{}'".format(chosen_categ,))
    about_cloth = cursor1.fetchall()

    buttons = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    forw = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "->", callback_data="->")
    backw = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "<-", callback_data="<-")
    bought = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = f"{about_cloth[0][0]} {about_cloth[0][1]}", callback_data="choisen_first")
    buttons.add(backw,forw)
    buttons.add(bought)

    next = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,
                            f"category: {about_cloth[0][0]}\n"
                            f"name: {about_cloth[0][1]}\n"
                            f"price: {about_cloth[0][2]}\n"
                            f"count: {about_cloth[0][3]}\n"
                            f"size: {about_cloth[0][4]}", reply_markup=buttons)#add photo
    
    user_choise[call.from_user.id] = about_cloth
    bot.register_next_step_handler(next,sending_cloth_from_database)
    
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

def sending_cloth_from_database (call):
    about_cloth = user_choise[call.from_user.id]

    try:
        
        if call.data == "->"  or call.data == "->1":
            if call.from_user.id not in list(click.keys()):
                    click[call.from_user.id] = 1
            else:
                    click[call.from_user.id]+=1
            try:

                cloth= user_choise[call.from_user.id][click[call.from_user.id]]

                buttons1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                forw1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "->", callback_data="->1")
                backw1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "<-", callback_data="1<-")
                bought1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = f"{cloth[0]} {cloth[1]}", callback_data="choisen_second")
                buttons1.add(backw1,forw1)
                buttons1.add(bought1)

                try:
                    
                    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text = 
                                        f"ctagory: {cloth[0]}\n"
                                        f"name: {cloth[1]}\n"
                                        f"price: {cloth[2]}\n"
                                        f"count: {cloth[3]}\n"
                                        f"size: {cloth[4]}\n", reply_markup=buttons1)#edit photo
                    
                except TypeError:
                    pass

            except IndexError:
                    
                    click.pop(call.from_user.id)
                    click[call.from_user.id] = 0

                    buttons = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                    forw = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "->", callback_data="->")
                    backw = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "<-", callback_data="<-")
                    bought = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = f"{about_cloth[0][0]} {about_cloth[0][1]}", callback_data="choisen_first")
                    buttons.add(backw,forw)
                    buttons.add(bought)

                    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id,message_id = call.message.message_id,text = 
                                        f"category: {about_cloth[0][0]}\n"
                                        f"name: {about_cloth[0][1]}\n"
                                        f"price: {about_cloth[0][2]}\n"
                                        f"count: {about_cloth[0][3]}\n"
                                        f"size: {about_cloth[0][4]}", reply_markup=buttons)#add photo
        if call.data == "<-" or call.data == "1<-":

            if call.from_user.id not in list(click.keys()):
                    click[call.from_user.id] = 1
            else:
                click[call.from_user.id]-=1
            try:

                cloth= user_choise[call.from_user.id][click[call.from_user.id]]

                buttons1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                forw1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "->", callback_data="->1")
                backw1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "<-", callback_data="1<-")
                bought1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = f"{cloth[0]} {cloth[1]}", callback_data="choisen_second")
                buttons1.add(backw1,forw1)
                buttons1.add(bought1)

                try:

                    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text = 
                                        f"ctagory: {cloth[0]}\n"
                                        f"name: {cloth[1]}\n"
                                        f"price: {cloth[2]}\n"
                                        f"count: {cloth[3]}\n"
                                        f"size: {cloth[4]}\n", reply_markup=buttons1)#edit photo
                    
                except TypeError:
                    pass

            except IndexError:

                click.pop(call.from_user.id)
                click[call.from_user.id] = 0

        if call.data == "choisen_first" or call.data == "choisen_second":

            buttons2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            forw2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "->", callback_data="->2")
            backw2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "<-", callback_data="2<-")
            bought2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "buy", callback_data="choise")
            buttons2.add(backw2,forw2)
            buttons2.add(bought2)

            cloth= user_choise[call.from_user.id][click[call.from_user.id]]
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text = 
                                        f"ctagory: {cloth[0]}\n"
                                        f"name: {cloth[1]}\n"
                                        f"price: {cloth[2]}\n"
                                        f"count: {cloth[3]}\n"
                                        f"size: {cloth[4]}\n", reply_markup=buttons2)#edit photo
            
    
        if call.data == "choise":

            cloth= user_choise[call.from_user.id][click[call.from_user.id]]

            prices = [LabeledPrice(label=f'{cloth[0]} {cloth[1]}', amount=int(str(cloth[2])+"00"))]

            bot.send_invoice(
                            call.from_user.id,  #chat_id
                            f'{cloth[0]}', #title
                            f'name: {cloth[1]}\nsize: {cloth[4]}', #description
                            
                            'chip', #invoice_payload
                            provider_token, #provider_token
                            'rub', #currency
                            prices, #prices
                            photo_url='https://бордшоп1.рф/pictures/product/big/38119_big.jpg',
                            photo_height=512,  # !=0/None or picture won't be shown
                            photo_width=512,
                            photo_size=512,
                            is_flexible=False,  # True If you need to set up Shipping Fee
                            start_parameter='time-machine-example')
            
            
    except AttributeError:
        pass


bot.polling(none_stop=True)`введите сюда код`
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.